# Relevant experience but I did a mediocre job.. should I include it in the cover letter?

Tags: application-cover-letter

I am writing a cover letter to apply for a paid PhD position. I was thinking if I should include the experience of doing my master's dissertation. The methodology is very similar to that of the project, but the problem is I did a mediocre job in the dissertation (got a C, meaning "Good"). I am ashamed by the grade and was thinking for this highly competitive position, a "good" job might be kind of bad.. Should I include it in the cover letter or just leave it and highlight my other experiences (which are not quite research-related)?

Comment: @NateEldredge "relevant" sorry for the typo

Comment: Goid question!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend somewhat on your country and your discipline, but in general a PhD is a research degree.  Research experience is the absolute most important and relevant experience.  Any research experience at all is better than none. You should mention it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think you are right about this. I am asked to include my transcripts anyway, hiding it might seem suspicious. It could also be a good idea to explain what I've gained throughout the process other than the grade.

Comment: This reminds me of a quote from a Scott Adams book: "Mathematically speaking, in the long run you are much better off doing a lousy job at something that looks good on a resume as opposed to doing a superb job at something that sounds dull."